# Persist text in html input during user input

Tags: jquery, html, input

I'm trying to append "USD" following user generated text as a unit in an html input. Right now I have some jquery that appends a $ before any input text, and then rebuilds the input, on each keyup

```
   $('#pledge_amt_gross_total').on('keyup',function(){
      var text = this.value;
      $(this).val("");
      if (text.indexOf("$") == -1){
         text = "$ " +text;
       }
      $(this).val(text);

    })
```

This works for anything `before` the user input text, but when I try to append anything `after` the user text, it doesnt work right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a version with a regex to find the number in the input and to wrap it in what you want. I added a timeout to prevent moving the cursor before user has finished his input. Try it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uH5uc/)

The code :

```
var formatTimeout;
$("#pledge_amt_gross_total").on("keyup", function() {
    var self = $(this);
    clearTimeout(formatTimeout);
    formatTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        var regex = /\d+/;
        var amount = self.val().match(regex);
        if (amount.length > 0) {
         self.val("$ " + amount + " USD");   
        } else {
              self.val("");       
        }   
    }, 1000);
});
```

You can change the time before the format is applied in the setTimout function if you want it to be faster or slower.

---

Edit :

If you want any number to be concat in the format : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uH5uc/1/)

```
var formatTimeout;
$("#pledge_amt_gross_total").on("keyup", function() {
    var self = $(this);
    clearTimeout(formatTimeout);
    formatTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        var regex = /\d+/g;
        var amount = self.val().match(regex);
        if (amount.length > 0) {
         self.val("$ " + amount.join("") + " USD");   
        } else {
              self.val("");       
        }   
    }, 1000);
});
```

I replaced the regex to be a global regex that will find any number. Then I join the numbers into one.

Comment: this is closer, yet if I type in something, wait for the values to fill in, then continue typing, it does not edit the value originally included, it simply adds it on at the end, which is then removed.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit my post with this version that takes any number and concats it : http://jsfiddle.net/uH5uc/1/

Comment: Note that with the concatenation, you don't actually need the setTimeout.

Answer (score 2):

Just change

```
if (text.indexOf("$") == -1){
    text = "$ " +text;
}
```

to

```
if (text.indexOf("$") == -1){
    text = "$ " +text;
}
if (!(test.indexOf("USD") >= 0)){
    text = text + " USD";
}
```

Comment: This does not work either. Because the value of the input then becomes  val="$ 55 USD", the next time I go to add more characters (or change the number) it creates a string like "$ 6USD55" where the numbers are added after the USD rather than before it after the $ sign

Comment: @AlexNeigher You have to check if the text already contains USD before adding it then. See my edit

Comment: I'm still getting strings like $ 4 USD4444444 in the input. The problem is after you press a key once it works fine, then you go press another key, it does not alter the original string, and just adds it back onto the end of var text @user2532739